# showing undifined index while uploading file

Tags: php, file, post, error-handling

I have an error saying:

> undefined index while uploading picture .

all other fields are getting but file type is not setting.

code below is page 1 where  I posting the image

```
<form name="adduser" id="adduser" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="{$ROOT_OBJECT}/addpointtypetodo/save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Point Type Tittle*</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="addPointTypeTittle" id="addPointTypeTittle" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Point Type Subtitle*</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="addPointTypeSubtitle" id="addPointTypeSubtitle" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Point Type Parse Tagline*</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="addPointTypeTagline" id="addPointTypeTagline" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Point Type Icon URL</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="select file.." id="addPointTypeIcon" name="addPointTypeIcon">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Point Type Marker URL</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="select file.." id="addPointTypeMarker" name="addPointTypeMarker">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="addPointTypeSubmit" id="addPointTypeSubmit" value="Save">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and this is the page getting this image:

```
$uploadedFile = $_FILES['addPointTypeIcon']['tmp_name'];
            $pointTypeIcon = 'images/category/' . $_FILES['addPointTypeIcon']['name'];
            if (is_uploaded_file($uploadedFile))
            {

                $this->model->fields = array();
                move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, $pointTypeIcon);
                array_push($this->model->fields, $pointTypeIndex);
                array_push($this->model->fields,  $pointTypeIcon);

                $this->model->saveIcon();


            }
//        }
//        if(isset($_FILES['addPointTypeMarker']))
//        {
            $uploadedFile = $_FILES['addPointTypeIcon']['tmp_name'];
            $pointTypeIcon = 'images/marker/' . $_FILES['addPointTypeMarker']['name'];
            if (is_uploaded_file($uploadedFile))
            {

                $this->model->fields = array();
                move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, $pointTypeIcon);
                array_push($this->model->fields, $pointTypeIndex);
                array_push($this->model->fields,  $pointTypeIcon);

                $this->model->saveMarker();


            }
```

It saying images not set.
please help.

Comment: What line are you getting an error at?

Comment: on the first line in php code $_FILES['addPointTypeIcon']['tmp_name'];

Comment: Make sure you set `method="post"` on the form. Additionally check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in php.ini to ensure you don't exceed those limits.

Comment: yes. that is the problem. post method solve problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `post` method on the form

```
<form name="adduser" id="adduser" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="{$ROOT_OBJECT}/addpointtypetodo/save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Files cannot be uploaded to PHP using the GET method, which is the default method for submitting forms.

[Relevant W3 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)